# yguard: Error obfuscating java class Unsupported class file major version 61

Tags: java, ant, yguard, openjdk-17

I'm switching my project from jdk1.8 to openjdk 17. Code works fine and ANT can generate the executable jar. Using Eclipse IDE.

The problem appears when trying to obfuscate with yguard 3.0.0 (through ant). The task is:

```
<target depends="create_javafx_jar" name="ofuscaJars2">     
        
      <taskdef name="yguard" classname="com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask" classpath="${yguard}"/>
        
      <echo level="info" message="OFUSCANDO JAR v2..." />       
        
        <if>
          <available file="${dir.jarfile}/assistcontrol.jar" type="file" />
          <then>            
          </then>
          <else>
            <fail message="Fichero ${dir.jarfile}/assistcontrol.jar no existe" />
          </else>
        </if>
                
         <yguard>           
            <inoutpair in="${dir.jarfile}/assistcontrol.jar"  out="${dir.obfuscatejar}/assistcontrol.jar" />
            
            <shrink logfile="${shrinklog}">
                <keep>
                    <!-- main method -->
                    <method name="void main(java.lang.String[])" class="core.MainClass" />
                </keep>
            </shrink>
            
            <externalclasses description="JARs que son invocados por AssistControl, deben tenerse en cuenta en la ofuscación">
                <fileset dir="${dir.jarfile}/jars">
                    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                </fileset>          
            </externalclasses>
            
            <rename mainclass="core.MainClass" logfile="${dir.obfuscatejar}/renaming.xml" replaceClassNameStrings="true">          
                  <property name="error-checking" value="pedantic"/>
            </rename>
          </yguard>
    </target>
```

The output is:

[shrink] ERROR: Unsupported class file major version 61
[shrink] Unsupported class file major version 61

I know 61 means java 17, so I've tried to change workspace compliance to 'Compiler compliance level -> 11', but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Asked in github, actual yguard version (3.0.0) don't support java 17.  Switching to openjdk 11 by now.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the [latest 3.1.0 release](https://github.com/yWorks/yGuard/releases/tag/3.1.0) claims to support JDK 17.